# What is wrong with this simple SQL? Fails when put in a stored procedure works otherwise

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

When I ran as is, it works perfectly fine but putting this exact code into a stored procedure in SQL 2005 fails.

I get this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetCurrentLoadDate, Line 23. 
>   Incorrect syntax near '@vardate'.

What is wrong with this call that it can work as a declaration and return the result set but fail if put in stored procedures?

```
declare @date datetime
declare @vardate varchar(10)

set @date = getDate()

set @vardate = CONVERT(varchar(10), @date ,101)

select tableloaded, insertdatetime, sourcesystemdatetime, FriendlyDescription
from dbo.tbl_loadSourcedates_dttm
where CONVERT(varchar(10), insertdatetime, 101) = @vardate
```

Thanks
Dhiren

Comment: Can you show your stored procedure create SQL?

Comment: Where's the rest of it?  The error is on line 23, this is way less than that many lines.

Comment: Yeah, showing us the code that doesn't work is probably more important than showing us the code that does. Also, converting a date column to varchar is awful practice. You should use a range `set @date = DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()); ... where insertdatetime >= @date AND insertdatetime < @date + 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing the `END` at the end of the stored proc definition that you neglected to show us. I get the same error If I append

```
create proc foo
as
begin
```

to the beginning of your posted code.

Comment: You are correct.  My bad. I coudln't figure what was going wrong as END is a defult value put in when u create a sp.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have exactly this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCurrentLoadDate

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    declare @date datetime

declare @vardate varchar(10)

set @date=getDate()

set @vardate=CONVERT(varchar(10), @date ,101)

select tableloaded,insertdatetime,sourcesystemdatetime,FriendlyDescription

from dbo.tbl_loadSourcedates_dttm

where CONVERT(varchar(10), insertdatetime ,101)=@vardate
END
GO
```

Because it looks to me that you are missing something when you declare your proc since you are getting a syntax exception on the very first line.